# jQuery inArray not matching but matched in IF statement

Tags: jquery

I am completely stumped on this one. i am trying to use the jQuery inArray function to check for string values withing in array of string values.

I pull both the contents of the Array and the strings i am checking against the array from the same db table and column, its literally the same data im comparing to itself basically, with a jQuery ajax handling it as json.

however the first & second check is returning false (-1) where as the third and forth strings match. What is really confusing me is when i do a comparison in an IF statement they are matching.

The values i check agains the Array each time are as follows (stored in the variable "competionName"):

```
 1. Friendly
 2. Friendly
 3. LEAFA Sunday Afternoon Division 1
 4. Edinburgh Cup - 1st Round
```

This is my array (Array is called "compsArray"):

```
Friendly,LEAFA Sunday Afternoon Division 1,Edinburgh Cup - 1st Round
```

This is my inArray code and my IF statement to try and debug.

```
if(compsArray[0] == competionName){
    console.log("match on IF comparison : '" + compsArray[0] + "' == '" + competionName + "'");
}else{
    console.log("Failed match on IF comparison : '" + compsArray[0] + "' !== '" + competionName + "'");
}


if($.inArray(competionName, compsArray)){
    console.log("match on inArray comparison : '" + competionName + "' is in '" + compsArray + "'");
}else{
    console.log("Failed match on inArray comparison : '" + competionName + "' is NOT in '" + compsArray + "'");
}
```

And this is what gets printed to the console.

> match on IF comparison : 'Friendly' == 'Friendly'
>
> Failed match on inArray comparison : 'Friendly' is NOT in
> 'Friendly,LEAFA Sunday Afternoon Division 1,Edinburgh Cup - 1st Round'
>
> match on IF comparison : 'Friendly' == 'Friendly'
>
> Failed match on inArray comparison : 'Friendly' is NOT in
> 'Friendly,LEAFA Sunday Afternoon Division 1,Edinburgh Cup - 1st Round'
>
> Failed match on IF comparison : 'Friendly' !== 'LEAFA Sunday Afternoon
> Division 1'
>
> match on inArray comparison : 'LEAFA Sunday Afternoon Division 1' is
> in 'Friendly,LEAFA Sunday Afternoon Division 1,Edinburgh Cup - 1st
> Round'
>
> Failed match on IF comparison : 'Friendly' !== 'Edinburgh Cup - 1st
> Round'
>
> match on inArray comparison : 'Edinburgh Cup - 1st Round' is in
> 'Friendly,LEAFA Sunday Afternoon Division 1,Edinburgh Cup - 1st Round'

The issue only seems to be on the first value "Friendly". I have checked that both values are of type string when the comparison is done. i have also checked for leading and trailing spaces (added the ' before and after the word to show there arent any in this example). I have also set the inArray statement to start from 0 just to check that, made no difference.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The result is a `0` since that's the Index, so you `if` will be `false` (`if(0) == false`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var compsArray = [
    "Friendly", "LEAFA Sunday Afternoon Division 1", "Edinburgh Cup - 1st Round"
  ];
  var competionName = "Friendly";

  if ($.inArray(competionName, compsArray) == 0) {
    console.log("match on inArray comparison : '" + competionName + "' is in '" + compsArray.join(", ") + "'");
  } else {
    console.log("Failed match on inArray comparison : '" + competionName + "' is NOT in '" + compsArray.join(", ") + "'");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> **Description:** Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

> The `$.inArray()` method is similar to JavaScript's native `.indexOf()` method in that it returns `-1` when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, `$.inArray()` returns `0`.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

Comment: Thanks for this @Twisty, after this comment i went back and looked at the inArray again, once i added a comparison on the end (==0) it all woekd as expected thank you!

Comment: @DanCrookes glad to hear that. I hope you will upvote the answer. If it did answer your question, I hope you will mark it as the answer.